# How to install Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, but not in a Project

Tags: c#, sql, connection

This is my first question here, although I've seen a lot of answers for the past few months, I'm a newby student on an University in Argentina, and I had an issue on a test the other day, due to the fact that I dind't have Microsoft.Data.SqlClient installed.

The thing is, each time I open a new project, I have to install Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, for me to be able to create connections from my C# Form, to my SQL Database.
What that causes, is my project folder to be heavier by having to install it here, and not in the Visual Studio folder itself.

To not generate confusion: I did try to use System.Data.SqlClient, for some reason this generated errors when creating a connection, which led me to use MicrosoftDataSqlClient(MDSC). I tried to install (MDSC) without having a project open, like this:

`+ Install-Package Microsoft.Data.SqlClient -Version 3.0.0`

Which returned the error:

`El entorno actual no tiene ninguna solución abierta. == The current environment has no open solution.`

Whenever I want to use MSDC, I go to NuGet Package Manager, and I install it there, which installs it on the project itself.

So, my question is, **how can I install Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, in Visual Studio, so I don't have to install it every time I open a new project?**

Comment: you ***do not want*** to do that. you ***do*** want to install your _program_ dependency into your _program_. also: you _can not_ do that.

Comment: It seems you are a bit lost regarding installing dependencies for your project. Here is a video that might help you: https://youtu.be/ohaz_sPLp4Y might be better than a long explanation

Answer (score 1):

One way is to create a class project (or WPF, Windows Forms, ASP.NET etc) project. Add the System.Data.SqlClient package. Next from Visual Studio menu, select Project, Export template, follow through to create a template (make sure if there is more than one project in the solution to select the correct project).

[Microsoft docs for export template.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-create-project-templates?view=vs-2019)

A dialog appears, fill out at least the description. Once done a .zip file is created and placed under

C:\Users**loginname**\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Templates\ProjectTemplates

If not Visual Studio 2019 e.g. Visual Studio 2017 then this is in the path.

You can even add stub methods in a class e.g.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace SqlServerLibrary.Classes
{
    public class Operations
    {
        public delegate void OnErrorHandler(Exception sender);
        public static event OnErrorHandler ErrorHandler;
        private static string _connectionString =>
            @"Data Source=TODO;Initial Catalog=TODO;Integrated Security=True";

        /// <summary>
        /// Change void to proper return type
        /// </summary>
        public static void Read()
        {

            using var cn = new SqlConnection() { ConnectionString = _connectionString };
            using var cmd = new SqlCommand() { Connection = cn };

            try
            {
                cn.Open();
                
                /*
                 * Write code. . .
                 */
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                ErrorHandler?.Invoke(exception);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Also note, in the above case C#9, .NET 5 is being used as shown in the .csproj file.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
      <LangVersion>9.0</LangVersion>
      <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.DependencyValidation.Analyzers" Version="0.11.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SqlClient" Version="4.8.2" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

If the version of SqlClient preferred changes you can then change it via manage packages or edit the project file manually, create a new template etc.

[image]

Comment: The question was about Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, not System.Data.SqlClient. The former has replaced the latter. You therefore need to replace this in the code as well: `using System.Data.SqlClient;` becomes `using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;`. I could not get it to run since my setup is on v4.6.1 and I do not seem to be able to update it (perhaps since I do not have admin rights), so that it needs System.Data.SqlClient. But I am not sure, it could also be my fault.